# Como fazer style num texto de um gráfico do Google Charts

Tags: google-charts

Bom dia! Tenho uma dúvida na utilização do ***Google Charts***.

Gostava de saber como faço para colocar `style` no texto. Sei que dá para fazer no título utilizando `titleTextStyle`, mas não sei como fazer para o texto em geral!

Também sei que de certa forma dá para fazer com o `annotations`, mas continuou sem dar. A parte do código do `annotations` está aqui (penso que seja aqui que esteja o erro):

> ```
> annotations: {
>     textStyle: {
>          fontSize: 10,
>          color: 'red'
>     }
> }
> ```

O meu código (em script) é o seguinte:

> ```
> <script type="text/javascript">
>             google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
>             google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
>
>             function drawChart() {
>                 var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
>                 data.addColumn('string', 'mes');
>                 data.addColumn('number', 'tickets');
>                 <?php
>                     if ($numReg_tickets_grafico = mysqli_num_rows($consulta_tickets_grafico) > 0) {
>                         while($result_tickets_grafico = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta_tickets_grafico)) {
>                 ?>
>                 data.addRows([
>                     ['<?= $result_tickets_grafico['data_mes'] ?>', <?= $result_tickets_grafico['id'] ?>]
>                 ]);
>                 <?php
>                         }
>                     }
>                 ?>
>
>                 var options = {
>                     'title':'Gráfico das Estatísticas',
>                     'width':600,
>                     'height':700,
>                     hAxis: {
>                         title: 'Mês'
>                     },
>                     vAxis: {
>                         title: 'Tickets Fechados'
>                     },
>                     annotations: {
>                         textStyle: {
>                             fontSize: 10,
>                             color: 'red'
>                         }
>                     }
>
>                 };
>
>                 var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
>                 chart.draw(data, options);
>             }
>         </script>
> ```

De seguida segue uma imagem a mostrar o estado atual do gráfico:

[image: ![Imagem do Gráfico feito com Google Charts]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Ku8.png)

Answer (score -1):

vcs pode tentar aceder lhe através do `HTML`  -> `document.getElementsByClassName("aqui mete o elemento");` -> `elemento.children` -> `children.innerHtml`
Pelo menos foi assim que eu editei o meu, boa sorte

Comment: na verdade não era bem isso o que eu queria! Eu quero editar por exemplo o tamanho da letra...

Comment: hmm exprimenta isto -> hAxis.textStyle: { fontSize: '10' }

Comment: Isso funciona, mas é para o texto que está como hAxis e não para por exemplo o texto que diz 05-2018.